# How can I get the IPFS key for using the Aragon OSx SDK?

Tags: javascript, ipfs, configuration

I'm trying to set up the `configParams` for the SDK and don't know where to find the IPFS key.

Do I need a different key depending on the network I'm in?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of now, please message the Aragon team (juliette@aragon.org) to grant you a key.

The IPFS key is important because whenever you're updating metadata or settings for DAOs or plugins, we need to pin that new information to our IPFS cluster first, so that the subgraph can have access to it through the SDK, UI etc.

Currently you can use ours, but we're designing a model where we'll be able to generate these keys automatically for dif environments. For now, I'll send you one that works for both networks and works in prod as well.